# How to convert the element from a row of a nested list into a nested dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-loops

Need to turn x:
`x=[['element',x,y,z],['a',2,4,6],['b',1,2,3],['c',6,7,8]]`

expected return:
`y={'a':{x:2,y:4,z:6},{'b':{x:1,y:2,z:3},{'c':{x:6,y:7,z:8}}`

---

I have now come up with few,

```
def parse(list):
    part1={}
    for f in range(len(list)):
       part2=dict(zip(list[0],list[f]))  #this part I use for generate inner part of dictionary(like {x:2,y:4,z:6})
       for i in list:
        if i[0] not in part1:
            part1[i[0]]=part2
        else:
            part1[i[0]]=part2  # this part I use to generate other part of each element of dict and combine with above(like {'a':{}})
    part1.pop('element')
    return(part1)
```

### however, the inner part returned from my code does not change according to the outside. It always shows three {x:6,y:7,z:8} instead of {x:2,y:4,z:6},{x:1,y:2,z:3},{x:6,y:7,z:8}. I'm kind of stuck in here.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: You've just edited [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66873685/how-to-convert-the-corresponding-element-from-a-nested-list-into-a-nested-dictio), it has been put in the reopen queue. Please don't duplicate it here with another user account!

Comment: Since the `if` and `else` have the exact same code, you don't need `if...else`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use unpacking with `zip`:

```
x=[['element','x','y','z'],['a',2,4,6],['b',1,2,3],['c',6,7,8]]
[_, *h1], *vals = zip(*x)
h2, *data = zip(*vals)
result = {a:dict(zip(h2, b)) for a, b in zip(h1, data)}
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'x': 2, 'y': 4, 'z': 6}, 'b': {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}, 'c': {'x': 6, 'y': 7, 'z': 8}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't name your own variables `list`.  That hides the Python type name.

```
def parse(lst):
    keys = lst[0][1:]
    result = {}
    for f in lst[1:]:
        result[f[0]] = dict(zip(keys,f[1:]))
    return result
x=[['element','x','y','z'],['a',2,4,6],['b',1,2,3],['c',6,7,8]]
print(parse(x))
```

Output:

```
C:\tmp>python x.py
{'a': {'x': 2, 'y': 4, 'z': 6}, 'b': {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}, 'c': {'x': 6, 'y': 7, 'z': 8}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce your code by iterating directly over the input list and using slices:

```
xs=[['element','x','y','z'],['a',2,4,6],['b',1,2,3],['c',6,7,8]]
y = {}

for x in xs[1:]:
    y[x[0]] = dict(zip(xs[0][1:], x[1:]))

print(y)
```

You can even turn this into a dict comprehension:

```
xs=[['element','x','y','z'],['a',2,4,6],['b',1,2,3],['c',6,7,8]]
y = {x[0]: dict(zip(xs[0][1:], x[1:])) for x in xs[1:}
print(y)
```